# How to increase thickness of slider conrol in mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I increase the thickness of a `CSliderCtrl` (slider control) in MFC?

Answer (score 0):

`MoveWindow()` can be used for any MFC control. Try this:

```
CRect rc;
slider.GetWindowRect(rc);    // Get the slider rectangle in absolute corrdinates
rc.InflateRect(30, 30);      // Do whatever you want with your rectangle;
ScreenToClient (rc);         // Convert to dialogs's coordinates
slider.MoveWindow(rc);       // Move it!
```

**Update:**
For further customization you have to make an owner-drawn `CListCtrl`. You may take [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csliderctrlex.aspx) as a good start for that

Comment: movewinow will increase size horizontally for scrollbar but how can we increase height of bar i.e. i am trying to increase thickness of slider bar